# How to use code from script with type=module

Tags: javascript, import, ecmascript-6, module

I can't figure out why this trivial code is not working:

**index.html:**

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="module" src="/showImport.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="showImportedMessage();">Show Message</button>
</body>

</html>
```

**showImport.js:**

```
import showMessage from '/show.js';

function showImportedMessage() {
    showMessage();
}
```

**show.js:**

```
export default "Why do I need this?";

export function showMessage() {
    alert("Hello!");
}
```

It is being served by NPM **http-server**. When I connect with Chrome (v65), I see the following error

```
(index):8 Uncaught ReferenceError: showImportedMessage is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):8)
onclick @ (index):8
```

If I get rid of `type=module` (and import/export by putting the `showMessage` function right in `showImport.js`) everything works, but *the whole purpose of this was to use modules*.

Also I had to add that useless `export default` statement, without it Chrome would complain:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/show.js' does not provide an export named 'default'
```

So what am I missing here?

Answer (score 146, accepted):

1. In a module context, variables don't automatically get declared globally. You'll have to attach them to `window` yourself. This is to prevent the scope ambiguity issues that you'd run into when using normal script tags.
2. The import/export usage is incorrect.

If you `export function xyz`, you must `import { xyz }`

If you `export default function xyz`, you must `import xyz` or `import { default as xyz }`

[See this article for more information on the module syntax.](http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html)

showImport.js:

```js
import { showMessage } from './show.js'

window.showImportedMessage = function showImportedMessage() {
    showMessage()
}
```

show.js:

```js
export function showMessage() {
    alert("Hello!")
}
```

Comment: Can you make an example of point 1? Is there a better/nicer way than assigning to window?

Comment: Assigning to window is fine. Makes it 100% clear that you're adding something into the global namespace (something that `var` in a traditional non-module script tag _doesn't_ make clear). In a larger project, you could accidentally have two variables named "user" if you aren't careful, for example. Good practices can help avoid silly issues like that, but modules prevent them from happening entirely.

Comment: @ElMac In order to create a global variable in a module context you need to add the variable straight to the HTML via script tags, e.g. `<script> let myVar; </script>`

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't work for me either on MS Edge 93. I literally copy-pasted the code in the question and answer. I just get no feedback at all.

Comment: @AndrewS Can you please _not_ make rude presumptions about how the question was answered Nonetheless, there's a typo; A `./` will be needed to import the show file. Fixed that, and it seems to work now. Even then, cross-browser differences are a maze, and I can't account for everything. Opening a new question for your specific case would be more productive.

Comment: @kingdaro: So can I say that adding `type="module"` is like programmatically importing with `import`(or `require`)?

Comment: @kingdaro Unrelated to this question, but I don't think StackOverflow tagged you correctly in the other question. I think you may know the answer to this question too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76076607/jsp-struggling-with-javascript-module-syntax - Seems related