# Call function from JavaScript module in HTML

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Say, I have the following JavaScript module using Vue:

```
import Vue from "./vue/vue.esm.browser.js";

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        message: 'Hello, world!',
    }
});

// Custom function for calling by the button
function changeMessage() {
    app.message = 'Hello from button!';
}
```

Now I refer to this module:

```
<script src="js/site.js" type="module"></script>
```

Then I try to call `changeMessage`:

```
<button onclick="changeMessage();">Press me</button>
```

However, I get the following error in console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: changeMessage is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Moreover, in Visual Studio I don't even get it in IntelliSense. When I remove `type="module"`, then everything works fine. How to make html see the module functions?

Comment: Look into module imports/exports.

Comment: @MarsAndBack Could you be more specific?

Comment: as @MarsAndBack stated, you need to understand how to export that function and import when needed. More on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49338193/how-to-use-code-from-script-with-type-module

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define the function on the global `window` object:

```html
<script type="module">

  window.greet = function () {
    alert('Hello')
  }

</script>

<button onclick="greet()">Hello</button>
```

Comment: I've updated my answer to demonstrate how it should work. If it isn't working for you, then there must be something else you're doing. Can you include a snippet?

Comment: You won't believe it, but if I rename file `site.js` to some other name (say, `site2.js`), then the code works! Does name `site.js` have special meaning?

Comment: I figured it out that this behavior is due to browser caching. I just took a look at JS file that browser loads - and it was outdated file. That's it! 

Comment: In any case, you should still learn about import/export if you actually want to make use of modules.