# Why can't my HTML file find the javascript function from a sourced module?

Tags: javascript, html

**some_file.js**

```
console.log("!")
function hello(){ 
    console.log("Hello!")
}
```

**index.html**

```
<script src="some_file.js" type="module"></script>
<script>
    hello()
</script>
```

When hosting and looking at `index.html`, I recieve a `ReferenceError` telling me that `hello` is not found. Following the advice to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58670635/call-function-from-javascript-module-in-html) thread other similar ones, I've placed something like `window.hello = hello` in my javascript file to no avail. I've also attempted exporting the function (which I think I'd only need to do if I were importing it in another javascript file).

Why am I getting a `ReferenceError`? The script is certainly being loaded, because I see the `!` print out in the console, but the function isn't being found.

Comment: Shouldn't you be invoking the hello() inside the file some_file.js

Comment: I'm slightly confused.  You do not appear to be using modularized javascript with these two files.  You're simply creating a js file that defines a method and including it on the html page.  That's not what is commonly referred to as "modular".  Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules

Comment: Ok, with your modified code, your source file is not exporting anything. `export function hello() ...`

Comment: @Taplar Sorry, I neglected to add the `type="module"` in my HTML

Comment: I think you need to export the function...

Comment: @evolutionxbox I mentioned that I've tried exporting it to no avail

Comment: @Sven.hig Yes, but—in my original file—I'm importing the `d3` library, and this does not work unless I use `type="module"` because imports have to be at the top level of a module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules
You have to export the function, then within a script tag with type module, import the module you want to use.

some_file.js

```
console.log("!")
export function hello(){ 
    console.log("Hello!")
}
```

index.html

```
<script type='module'>
    import {hello} from "./some_file.js" 
    hello()
</script>
```

Comment: _Uncaught TypeError: Error resolving module specifier “some_file.js”. Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”._

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I needed. Thank you

Comment: That's no problem. Thanks for updating the answer 

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

**index.html**

```
<script src="some_file.js" type="module">
    hello()
</script>
```

Comment: This is not valid; when the type is module, there cannot be any text in between the script tags (else the error `Expected expression, got <` comes up)