# Can I import from a JavaScript module that was defined inline via HTML script tag?

Tags: javascript, browser, module, es6-modules

If I export from an JavaScript module that's *inline* in my HTML as in `<script type="module"> …inline code here… </script>` is there any way I can **reference** that module, and import it from another module?

My JS app has some generated code/configuration which would be quite convenient to rendering dynamically within some already-outgoing HTML instead of creating a separate new endpoint just for that data.

Using Django template syntax as a rough example, and generating JS code in a not particularly production-grade way just to keep it simple, consider if I had some "template.html":

```html
<script id="config_module" type="module">
const configData = {
   field1: "{{ something }}",
   field2: [{% for n in someother %}{{ n }}, {% endfor %}]
};

export default configData;
</script>

<script type="module" src="{% static "myapp/main_code.mjs" %}"></script>
```

Where the content of "myapp/main_code.mjs" would be something like:

```js
import config from "#config_module";     // ← ???

if (config.field1 === "whatever") alert("Something was whatever!");
```

I can think of other ways to accomplish something similar, such as:

- have the inline module assign a global variable like `window.myPrefix_config = { … }` for the other module to grab (see [How to use code from script with type=module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49338193/how-to-use-code-from-script-with-type-module) for example)
- avoid the inline JS and give that content its own separately-rendered URL to `import config from "/server/generates/config.mjs"` where needed

But I am curious about the underlying question itself here: when I define a module *inline* is there any way to import it from other modules in the same browser context? Or in terms of the [HostResolveImportedModule](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-scripts-and-modules.html#sec-hostresolveimportedmodule) spec, do browsers support any sort of `ModuleSpecifier` syntax that can resolve to an inline script, a working version of my `import … from "#config_module"` pseudocode?

Comment: @Bergi Ah yes, I think that is asking the same thing. Thanks for the pointer!