# How to access function from a javascript type=module

Tags: javascript, module

I have three files, let it be `index.html`, `module.js`, `main.js`, `index.js`

**INDEX.HTML**

```
....
<body
    <script type="module "src="main.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
...
```

**MODULE.JS**

```
....
function foo(text){
  alert(text)
}

export default foo;
...
```

**MAIN.JS**

```
import foo from "./module.js"
function bar(text){
   foo("FOOBAR")
}
```

**INDEX.JS**

```
bar() // not "type="module"
```

Can I execute `bar()` from `index.js` without giving attribute `type="module"` in html?

Comment: As far as I know modules don't declare global variables. Hence they won't be available as "bar", you need to import them or make them global from the module itself

Comment: "_Can I execute bar() from index.js ..._" - NO, once a file is declared as a module, it becomes a closure, as if it is its own namespace. The only way to access its features is to import them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible. As Ruben mentioned in the comment, you need to import the main.js into your index.js to have access to its bar() function, else you will get a

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: bar is not defined
```

error

Checking these questions may be helpful :

[how-to-use-code-from-script-with-type-module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49338193/how-to-use-code-from-script-with-type-module)

[use-functions-defined-in-es6-module-directly-in-html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53630310/use-functions-defined-in-es6-module-directly-in-html)