# Unable to link JS files to html page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native

I am new to programming and I'm learning react. I don't know why the Js files will not link to my html page. I am not getting any errors when I run the code

## This is my html page

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="card.css">
    <title>Digital Business Card</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <script type="module" src="./index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

This is one of my JS files Main.js
===================================

import React from "react"

export default function Main() {
    <div>
        <h4>Carlos Hernandez</h4>
        <h5>Front End Developer</h5>
        <h6>CanningJars.com</h6>
    </div>
}
```

## this is another JS file Img.js

```
import React from "react"

const CheetahPic = new URL("./images/cheetah.png", import.meta.url)

export default function Img() {
    return(
        <>
            <div>
                <img src={CheetahPic} />
            </div>
        </>
    )
        
}
```

## This is another JS file App.js

```
import React from "react"
import Main from "./components/Main.js"
import Img from "./components/Img.js"
import "./card.css"

export default function App() {
    <div className="container">
        <Img/>
        <Main/>
        <Footer/>
    </div>
}
```

## This is another JS file index.js

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import App from "./components/App.js"


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

[Screenshot of my directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biDsP.jpg)

Comment: Without knowing your directory structure it's difficult to help. Is your script file in the same location as your HTML file? You should set it up in a standard fashion, such as how Create-React-App would.

Comment: You are not returning anything in your `Main` and `App` components

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing `type="module"` from your HTML Page?
As said by another user in a similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49338383/19497251): "In a module context, variables don't automatically get declared globally."

Comment: Yes I have it still isn't showing anything I appreciate the response.

Answer (score 0):

You said you have a file named `indez.js` but you are linking `index.js` maybe it is an simple typo.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. I'm guessing that the typo occurred when the post was created.

Comment: @isherwood I can understand that, and it could have been a typo in post. But maybe it isn't, and it can help the op.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo when writing the question my actual file is names index.js