# ReferenceError: exported function is not defined at onload

Tags: html, dom, module, onload

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="module" src="topo_space.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="main()">
</body>
</html>
```

topo_space.js:

```
export function main(){
    const innerHTML = `<svg id="main_svg" width="959" height="704"></svg>`;
    console.log(innerHTML);
    document.body.innerHtml = innerHTML;
}
```

Getting error:

```
topo_space.html:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: main is not defined at onload
```

I want to stick to using module, because the js can itself further import a json as module, which I find extremely cool.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this thread to read more information about this problem:

[How to use code from script with type=module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49338193/how-to-use-code-from-script-with-type-module)

The answer is:

```js
window.main = function main() {
  const innerHTML = `<svg id="main_svg" width="959" height="704"></svg>`;
  console.log(innerHTML);
  document.body.innerHtml = innerHTML;
};
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="module" src="topo_space.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body onload="main()"></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thx, it works (error msg no longer there, main() gets called). For some reason document.body.innerHtml doesn't load. Silently (there is absolutely no error msg in the console).

Comment: Had to change the body to embed the svg tag on the html side. Then in main() code getElementById("main-svg").innerHTML=innerHTML. And it eventually worked out. So this second issue was minor.