# How to call newuser() function in button onlick? (Firebase)

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
        <title>DB Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a><h1>DB Test</h1></a>

        <div class="input-box">
            <input id="email" type="text" name="username" placeholder="email">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
        </div>

        <div class="input-box">
            <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="pw">
            <label for="password">password</label>
        </div>

        <input type="button" id="button" value="submit" onclick="newuser();">

        <script type="module">
            // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
            import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.4.0/firebase-app.js";
            import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.4.0/firebase-auth.js";
            // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
            // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

            // Your web app's Firebase configuration
            const firebaseConfig = {
                ...
            };

            // Initialize Firebase
            const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
            const auth = getAuth();

            const email = document.getElementById('email').value
            const password = document.getElementById('password').value
            function newuser(){
            createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
            .then((userCredential) => {
              // Signed in
              const user = userCredential.user;
              // ...
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              const errorCode = error.code;
              const errorMessage = error.message;
              // ..
            });
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to call newuser() function in script tag at onclick event in button, but error occurs like 'newuser is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick'. I don't know how to connect html code and javascript code(script tag) naturally, and I want to make newuser function occur when I click the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because with `<script type="module">` you indicate that your script should be treated as a [module](https://javascript.info/modules-intro).

Since each module has its own top-level scope, variables and functions from a module are not seen in other scripts or in the HTML part of the page. See [here](https://javascript.info/modules-intro#module-level-scope) for more details.

You could solve your problem by attaching the function to `window` to use it globally:

```js
      window.newuser = () => {
        const email = document.getElementById('email').value;
        const password = document.getElementById('password').value;
        console.log(password);
        createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
          .then((userCredential) => {
            // Signed in
            const user = userCredential.user;
            // ...
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            const errorCode = error.code;
            const errorMessage = error.message;
            // ..
          });
      };
```

But this not really recommended... You should use a module bundler like Webpack, as explained in the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/module-bundling#using_firebase_with_webpack). "From version 9 and higher, the Firebase JavaScript SDK is optimized to work with the optimization features of module bundlers to reduce the amount of Firebase code included in your final build."

---

In addition, note that it is not recommended to use `onclick()` see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17378538/3371862) (among many answers in SO): better use [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Answer (score 0):

Try put the script tag with your newuser function into . You need declare the function first, then use it.

```html
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="module">
         …………
        </script>
        <title>DB Test</title>
</head>
```

Comment: Where do I put the script tag with newuser function into? Head tag?

Comment: Answer modified.

Comment: I change the position of script tag, but reference error still occurs

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49338193/how-to-use-code-from-script-with-type-module